# Cannot extend Auto-complete Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I have follow some toturial and documentation.
I go to Preferences -> Browse Packages.

Then create a file called "Rails.sublime-completions" in Data/Package/User.
Its content:

```
{
   "scope": "text.html - source - meta.tag, punctuation.definition.tag.begin",

   "completions":
   [
      "anExample"
   ]
}
```

all setting are in Default.

Comment: If this is a completion for Rails then the value of `scope` should probably be just `source.ruby.rails`.

Comment: nothing happens, what is scope mean???